# How to use a c# method in a sql stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I wanted to use linq as so:

```
MyDBEntities context = new MyDBEntities();
context.MyTable.Where(i => MyMethod(i.column, valueToTest).ToList();
```

with

```
public bool MyMethod(Object a, Object b)
```

but apparently using such a method with isn't possible

so I was hopping I could use the methode in a stored procedure I would be able to call with linq

do you think is it possible ?

Comment: I'm sorry but your question makes no sense, the title talks about a Stored Procedure, your sample code uses (i assume) Linq2Sql, and what you're trying to achieve, is just bad... I think you're looking for CLR Stored Procedures. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx - But what are you trying to do that SQL doesn't allow you to do already?

Comment: @Phill, it looks like he wants to write a method that will compare a specified column against a specified value and return a bool based on the result.

Comment: @Nick - It's such a vague question, I'm not sure why it's being upvoted, there isn't really much to go by, too open for assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally it is possible to create C# function and use it in SQL Server (2005 and newer) but it is not so simple - you must use SQL CLR which means separate project for your function, special references, special types, etc. At last you must deploy the assembly to SQL server to be able to use the function in SQL. General documentation also covering how to create custom function:

[Creating SQL Server Objects in Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997440.aspx)

Once you have your function on SQL server you can use it within stored procedure and you can use it within query. I'm actually not sure if you can import these functions into Linq-to-sql or EF model and use them in Linq-to-sql or Linq-to-entities queries.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here for a complete sample:

[Calling custom methods in LINQ-to-SQL](http://www.atrevido.net/blog/2007/09/05/Calling+Custom+Methods+In+LINQtoSQL.aspx)

Comment: I'm afraid this works only for very small subset of functions because you cannot map arbitrary function - SQL doesn't know how to execute it. It works only for functions which are internally mapped to SQL counterparts like `Math.xxx`, `String.xxx`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly.

Let's say that MyTable is a database table that contains the columns `Name`, and `Address`
Here's how you would get a value back whether the results contain the specified value you passed.

```
public void SomeMethod()
    {
        MyTable table= new MyTable();

        bool b=  MyMethod(table.Name, "Fred");
       if(b)
         //Do something
       else
         //Do something else
    }

    public bool MyMethod(MyTable a, object value)
    {
        using(var context= new MyDBEntities())
        {
            return context.MyTable.Where(i => a == value).Any();
        }
    }
```

This is what the database table 'MyTable' looks like behind the scenes.(the data context generated this)

```
public class MyTable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

So you can see in the first method I pass `table.Name` to `MyMethod`, that's only possible because `MyTable` has a pubic property called `Name`. Also notice that we are using type Object for the value, as the parameter could an int, a string, a date time, who knows.

Note: This is untested code, but should get off to right track if I understand you correctly.